# Why Firebase Database REST API returns no-cache header

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, okhttp, cache-control

I have an android application which is using **OkHttp** client and i request some data in my firebase realtime database using it's rest api [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database). Firebase implements ETAG and OkHttp is properly doing conditional requests. But it also returns `Cache-Control: no-cache` header which means OkHttp will use cache only during *conditional-get*, but i need to control cache (set `max-stale`) or to use cache when there is no network.

Can i request Firebase so it gives different `Cache-control` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Database returns that header to indicate intermediate layers should not cache the data, as it may be depend on authentication state.

There is no way to tell the database to not return that flag.

Keep in mind: while OkHttp may not cache the data, your application *can* store the results. This is the intended behavior, since your application *can* actually verify that the user is authorized to access the data, while OkHttp has no way to do so.

Comment: yes that make sense, thanks. in my case though read permission is open without any authentication, so the header in my case could be omitted right?

Comment: There is no way to tell the database to not return that flag.